# Load all page under same URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a idea to load all the page/path under same URL or root domain. Is it possible to do this?.

Example :

Let say my domain is `example.com` and i have 3 pages `index.php`, `contact.php`, `about/social.php` and each file have different content. I want to load all file under my root domain if they click URL of any page in root file `index.php`

Example 2 :

1. When someone visit example.com it will automatically (default) load `index.php` content and it have a link to other pages like `contact.php` and `about/social.php`
2. When someone click a link of `contact.php` inside my root domain `example.com`, it will load the contact of `contact.php` but it should not change to `example.com/contact.php` instead it remain same `example.com` with the content of `contact.php`

Is this possible?. If yes, then you can help me with code/syntax in PHP or Javascript or htaccess

Comment: Yes, it is possible using ajax or redirections, but you should take in consideration that SEO impact about it.  If all pages are under same URL that could damage your SEO in each one.

Comment: @masterguru can you help me with code?. Yes i know it damage SEO but i am designing it for paid marketing & advertising. so SEO is not needed for it.

Comment: What have you tried with code?  Edit your question and add it here.  I am sorry but [we are not a free code writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372166/we-are-not-a-code-writing-service-comments-are-they-the-good-the-bad-or-the-u).

Comment: While it is possible, it isn't good for user experience nor good for SEO.  In short, this is a bad idea.